# Double discrete integration of periodic function with R: doubly integrated function contains linear artifact

Tags: r, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I need to integrate a signal from accelerometer, in order to get speed and position over time.

I'm trying the code on some code-generated acceleration data:
1)squarewave
2)sawtooth
3)sin

The speed function obtained is ok, the problem is with the position function obtained integrating speed. IN each case (squarewave, sawtooth, sin) the doubly discrete-integrated funtion shows a linear term superposed to the expected oscillating one.

I've perfomed this discrete-integration with both `diffinv()` function and with this custom function I've written:

```
#function that, given a function sampled at some time values, calculates its primitive
calculatePrimitive<-function(f_t, time, initialValue){
        F_t<-0
        F_t[1]<-initialValue
        for (i in 2:length(f_t)) {
                F_t[i] <- F_t[i-1] + (( (f_t[i]+f_t[i-1])/2 )*(time[i]-time[i-1]) ) 
        }
        F_t
}
```

The result is the same, no matter which function i use to performe the discrete integration, and it is shown in the attached graphs for cases 1) to 3).

[image: squarewave]

[image: sawtooth]

[image: sinusoid]

I don't understand why this happen when, no matter what is the acceleration data, the discrete integration is applied to data that have been obtained by descrete integration themselves.

Comment: How is this Rstudio related?

Comment: not R studio related. There's no Rstudio tag indeed. I'm removing the "studio" word from tittle